# How to create and write Excel .xls file using C#

Tags: c#

I have few tests which run three times and there average is calculated through c# code.I am able to write the three test times and there average to the xls file if created before in the below picture format[image: xls file format] . But now I have to run each test every hour everyday through a batch file using windows scheduler. I want to create the xls file dynamically in every hour in below mentioned format with a specific name so that at the first iteration the file is created and for next 19 iteration it should write in the same file then next hour new file created with a specific name.How to create and write the excel file dynamically ?????
If there is any other simple procedure plz suggest that. The code which I was using to write in already created xls file is :`/*

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Ranorex;

namespace PEPI_Performance.Utility
{
/// <summary>
/// Description of ExcelWriter.
/// </summary>

public class ExcelWriter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new instance.
    /// </summary>
    public ExcelWriter()
    {
        // Do not delete - a parameterless constructor is required!
    }


    public void Driver(int row , int col, string time, string sheetName){

        string sDataFile = "Ranorex_Reports.xls";
        string sFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(sDataFile);

        string sOldvalue = "Automation\\bin\\Debug\\" + sDataFile;
        sFilePath = sFilePath.Replace(sOldvalue,"")+
 "PEPI_Performance\\ExecutionReport\\" + sDataFile;
        fnOpenExcel(sFilePath,sheetName);
        writeExcel(row,col,time);
        fnCloseExcel();
    }
    Excel.Application   exlApp ;
    Excel.Workbook exlWB ;
    Excel.Sheets excelSheets ;
    Excel.Worksheet exlWS;
    //Open Excel file
    public int fnOpenExcel(string sPath, string iSheet){

        int functionReturnValue = 0;
        try {

            exlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass(); 
            exlApp.Visible = true;
    exlWB=
   exlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
  Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);

            // get all sheets in workbook
            excelSheets = exlWB.Worksheets;

            // get some sheet
            //string currentSheet = "Cycle1";
            exlWS = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(iSheet);
            functionReturnValue = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            functionReturnValue = -1;
            Report.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        return functionReturnValue;
    }


    // Close the excel file and release objects.
    public int fnCloseExcel(){
        //exlWB.Close();

        try{
            exlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
            exlApp.Quit();

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exlWS);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exlWB);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exlApp);

            GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Report.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeExcel(int i, int j , string time){
        Excel.Range exlRange = null;
        exlRange = (Excel.Range)exlWS.UsedRange;
        ((Excel.Range)exlRange.Cells[i,j]).Formula = time;

    }

   }
 }
```

`

Comment: Is your question how to generate a filename with the date and time in it?

Comment: how to create an excel file and that excel file name can be with date and time. Inside it I want to write as the attached picture. @CodeCaster

Comment: What kind of unit tests are they? Visual Studio? nUnit?

Comment: I'm using Ranorex Automation tool and the script is used for a performance test. @WyattEarp

Comment: @Mudit Just to provide a new way of looking at the problem, it sounds like you are running 20 tests and are writing to the Excel file during each test.  Instead, what if you just collected the data during each test, then wrote the values after the tests finished?  This would eliminate the need to keep track of the Excel file between tests.  I'm not familiar with Ranorex, but I imagine that there is some kind of a teardown method where you could do this.

Comment: @WyattEarp yes, exactly I'm running 20 tests and writing to the excel file. I can store the data in a collection and then write at last after first execution but after second execution it will overwrite my data bcz the test has to run automatically every hour for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all honesty you might be better off using a csv file, that way from your ranorex tests you can simply use system.IO.File to write the output text to the file, and the nice thing about the csv format is it can then be opened in excel

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to handle this using a data grid.

The example below accepts a DataSet (you could pass a list or table).

Then on the FLY a GridView is created and exported to Excel. I use this method on many sites.

```
public static void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds, string filename)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        // first let's clean up the response.object
        response.Clear();
        response.Charset = "";

        // set the response mime type for excel
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

        // create a string writer
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                // instantiate a datagrid
                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
                dg.DataSource = ds;
                dg.DataBind();
                dg.RenderControl(htw);
                response.Write(sw.ToString());
                response.End();
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I have to write the code for an automation testing using Ranorex automation tool.

Comment: @SRUFThru - thats a nice trick. I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: Mudit, I do not understand. It looks like you are writing custom code, not sure your point on Ranorex(never heard of it)

Comment: @SURFThru I'm referring a code on [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx) can you help me what to edit in this code so that I can create a file with name according to system date and time and save it in particular location in .xls format.